# Переход с python aiogram 2 -> aiogram 3.0. Не могу найти класс для импорта

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x, aiogram-2.x

### В общем есть такой большой код. Его суть - блокировать спам боту. Глубоко вникать не нужно

В aiogram версии 3 не импортируются:

- `from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler, current_handler`
- `from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled`

### Вот код:

```
import asyncio
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler, current_handler
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types
 


# * SETTINGS
RATE_LIMIT      = 1   # (sec)
MUTED_MESSAGE   = 'Не спамьте!'
UNMUTED_MESSAGE = 'Можете писать.'



# ? INFO
# * setup
# from antiflood_module import ThrottlingMiddleware, rate_limit
# dp.middleware.setup(ThrottlingMiddleware())

# * cutom rate limit
# @rate_limit(5)







def rate_limit(limit: int):
    """
    Decorator for configuring rate limit and key in different functions.

    :param limit:
    :return:
    """

    def decorator(func):
        setattr(func, 'throttling_rate_limit', limit)
        return func

    return decorator


class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rate_limit = RATE_LIMIT
        self.prefix = 'antiflood_'
        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        """
        This handler is called when dispatcher receives a message

        :param message:
        """
        # Get current handler
        handler = current_handler.get()

        # Get dispatcher from context
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        # If handler was configured, get rate limit and key from handler
        if handler:
            limit = getattr(handler, 'throttling_rate_limit', self.rate_limit)
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            limit = self.rate_limit
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        # Use Dispatcher.throttle method.
        try:
            await dispatcher.throttle(key, rate=limit)
        except Throttled as t:
            # Execute action
            await self.message_throttled(message, t)

            # Cancel current handler
            raise CancelHandler()

    async def message_throttled(self, message: types.Message, throttled: Throttled):
        """
        Notify user only on first exceed and notify about unlocking only on last exceed

        :param message:
        :param throttled:
        """
        handler = current_handler.get()
        dispatcher = Dispatcher.get_current()
        if handler:
            key = getattr(handler, 'throttling_key', f"{self.prefix}_{handler.__name__}")
        else:
            key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        # Calculate how many time is left till the block ends
        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta

        # Prevent flooding
        if throttled.exceeded_count <= 2 and MUTED_MESSAGE:
            await message.reply(MUTED_MESSAGE)

        # Sleep.
        await asyncio.sleep(delta)

        # Check lock status
        thr = await dispatcher.check_key(key)

        # If current message is last with current key AND message is setuped
        if thr.exceeded_count == throttled.exceeded_count and UNMUTED_MESSAGE: 
            await message.reply(UNMUTED_MESSAGE)
```

### Нашел в документации `from aiogram.filters.exceptions import ExceptionTypeFilter` но так и не понял, что оно делает.

Может их куда перенесли или сделали теперь по другому?

Answer (score 1):

Самому пришлось переписывать весь проект со 2-ой на 3-ю версию aiogram и столкнулся с такой же трудностью. Увы, здесь придётся переписывать весь мидлварь.

Вот моя текущая реализация мидлваря для тротлинга (первоисточник - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519367/aiogram-3-x-anti-flood-middleware?newreg=205a16ee2d1d4fb4bfc6b07009a9eedb):

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import *
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message
import redis.asyncio.client 
import time
import aioredis

class ThrottlingMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, redis: aioredis.Redis, limit=2, key_prefix='antiflood_'):
        self.rate_limit = limit
        self.prefix = key_prefix
        self.throttle_manager = ThrottleManager(redis=redis)

        super(ThrottlingMiddleware, self).__init__()

    async def __call__(
        self,
        handler: Callable[[Message, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
        event: Message,
        data: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Any:

        try:
            await self.on_process_event(event)
        except CancelHandler:
            # Cancel current handler
            return

        try:
            result = await handler(event, data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return

        return result

    async def on_process_event(self, event: Message) -> Any:
        limit = self.rate_limit
        key = f"{self.prefix}_message"

        # Use ThrottleManager.throttle method.
        try:
            await self.throttle_manager.throttle(key, rate=limit, user_id=event.from_user.id, chat_id=event.chat.id)
        except Throttled as t:
            # Execute action
            await self.event_throttled(event, t)
            # Cancel current handler
            raise CancelHandler()

    async def event_throttled(self, event: Message, throttled: Throttled):
        # Calculate how many time is left till the block ends
        delta = throttled.rate - throttled.delta
        # Prevent flooding
        if throttled.exceeded_count <= 2:
            await event.answer(f'Too many requests.\nTry again in {delta:.2f} seconds.')


class ThrottleManager:
    bucket_keys = [
        "RATE_LIMIT", "DELTA",
        "LAST_CALL", "EXCEEDED_COUNT"
    ]

    def __init__(self, redis: redis.asyncio.client.Redis):
        self.redis = redis

    async def throttle(self, key: str, rate: float, user_id: int, chat_id: int):
        now = time.time()
        bucket_name = f'throttle_{key}_{user_id}_{chat_id}'

        data = self.redis.hmget(bucket_name, self.bucket_keys)
        data = {
            k: float(v.decode()) 
               if isinstance(v, bytes) 
               else v 
            for k, v in zip(self.bucket_keys, data) 
            if v is not None
        }
        # Calculate
        called = data.get("LAST_CALL", now)
        delta = now - float(called)
        result = delta >= rate or delta <= 0
        # Save result
        data["RATE_LIMIT"] = rate
        data["LAST_CALL"] = now
        data["DELTA"] = delta
        if not result:
            data["EXCEEDED_COUNT"] = int(data["EXCEEDED_COUNT"])
            data["EXCEEDED_COUNT"] += 1
        else:
            data["EXCEEDED_COUNT"] = 1

        self.redis.hmset(bucket_name, data)

        if not result:
            raise Throttled(key=key, chat=chat_id, user=user_id, **data)
        return result


class Throttled(Exception):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.key = kwargs.pop("key", '<None>')
        self.called_at = kwargs.pop("LAST_CALL", time.time())
        self.rate = kwargs.pop("RATE_LIMIT", None)
        self.exceeded_count = kwargs.pop("EXCEEDED_COUNT", 0)
        self.delta = kwargs.pop("DELTA", 0)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.chat = kwargs.pop('chat', None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Rate limit exceeded! (Limit: {self.rate} s, " \
               f"exceeded: {self.exceeded_count}, " \
               f"time delta: {round(self.delta, 3)} s)"


class CancelHandler(Exception):
    pass
```

Функция rate_limit() Вам больше не понадобится.
Обязательно создайте объект класса Redis, поскольку Вам необходимо записывать в него данные о пользователях для отслеживания частоты получения апдейтов от их действий:

```
from redis import Redis

redis = Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT, db=REDIS_DB, decode_responses=True)
```

Теперь Вам нужно импортировать новый мидлварь в файл с Вашей функцией и добавить в нужный роутер новый мидлварь, чтобы тот начал обрабатывать поступающие апдейты:

```
router = Router()
router.message.middleware(ThrottlingMiddleware(redis))
```